# Could not download PDF file using FPDF and php

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I need to write data from MySQL table to PDF file and download using `PHP and MySQL`. For this I am using `FPDF` to create PDF file but in my case its not working as expected and throwing the below error.

Error:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  file_put_contents(report_22-05-2019 18:36:24.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/var/www/hlwcab.com/public_html/cab/include/libs/fpdf.php</b> on line <b>1021</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Unable to create output file: report_22-05-2019 18:36:24.pdf'
```

I am providing my code below.

```
require_once '../../../include/libs/fpdf.php';
class PDF extends FPDF{
    // Page header
    function Header(){
        // Logo
        $this->Image('../../../admin/img/HLW-CabManagementLogo.png',10,-1,70);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',13);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(80);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(80,10,'Report List',1,0,'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }
    // Page footer
    function Footer(){
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }

}
if ($_REQUEST["action"]=="downloadMonthlyReportData") {
        $data=array();
        $start_time=$_POST['start_time'];
        $end_time=$_POST['end_time'];
        $sql="select * from cb_wallet_driver_logs order by id desc";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $number_of_rows= count($row);
            if ($number_of_rows > 0) {
                $slno=1;
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    $last_update=$value['last_update'];
                    $owner_id=$value['owner_id'];
                    $sql="select * from cb_owner_info where owner_id=:owner_id";
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':owner_id', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($owner_id)));
                    if ($stmt->execute()) {
                        $orow = $stmt->fetchAll();
                        $number_of_orows= count($orow);
                        if ($number_of_orows > 0) {
                            foreach ($orow as $key => $val) {
                                $owner_name=$val['name'];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $dt = new DateTime($last_update);
                    $odate=$dt->format('d-m-Y');
                    $ndate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($odate));
                    $stdate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($start_time));
                    $endate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($end_time));
                    if ($ndate >= $stdate && $ndate <= $endate) {
                        $data[]=array("sl_no"=>$slno,"owner_name"=>$owner_name,"last_update"=>$last_update,"book_id"=>$value['book_id'],"operator_total"=>$value['operator_total'],"ride_total"=>$value['ride_total']);
                    }
                    $slno++;
                }
            }
        }
        $result1=array();
        if (count($data) > 0) {
            $pdf = new PDF();
            //header
            $pdf->AddPage();
            //foter page
            $pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
            $column[]=array("Sl No","Owner name","Date","Booking ID","Operator Total","Ride Total");
            //print_r($column);exit;
            foreach ($column as $key => $value) {
                $pdf->Cell(40,12,$value,1);
            }
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $pdf->Ln();
                foreach ($value as $column) {
                    $pdf->Cell(40,12,$column,1);
                }
            }
            $today=date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
            $filename='report_'.$today.'.pdf';
            $pdf->Output($filename, "F");
            $result1["msg"] = "Succesfully Downloaded...";
        }else{
            header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
            $result1["msg"] = "No record to download...";
        }
        //print_r($result1);exit;
        echo json_encode($result1);
    }
```

Here I am fetching the data from MySQL which is happening and writing those data into PDF file. Also as per error I set the `777` permission but still those errors are coming. Here I need to create the PDF file and download it in the browser.

Comment: You need to give the directories permission for your webserver to write files. You are not specifying a path, so i guess FPDF will use it's default path.

Comment: I set the `777` permission to include directory but still same issue.

Comment: are you sure you set it on the correct directory? Because the error indicates you may not have done. If it was correct, you shouldn't get the error.

Comment: I’d start by giving that file a better name – having stuff like `:` in there is asking for trouble. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words If that’s not it, then try and specify a full path instead of just a file name.

Comment: Now the error gone after setting the right path but it could not download in browser only written inside directory.

Comment: "it could not download" ...that's not really a surprise. None of your code even attempts to offer the file for download. Instead you just return a JSON response. You can return either the file, or the JSON. It's up to you. And you can easily google how to offer a file for download using PHP. Oh an if you are requesting this PHP script via AJAX, then it won't work anyway because you can't download files via AJAX. In that scenario you'd have to initiate a separate HTTP request to carry out the download, or alternatively not use AJAX in the first place.

Comment: P.S. If the file was not found, why would you return a 401 (Unauthorised) response? That's completely inappropriate. That should be returned when you require the user to send some authentication details such as password or access token. If something isn't found, then return a 404 (i.e. Not Found). The clue for which status to use is pretty obvious from the name, surely??! Also...why specify HTTP 1.0? It's a **long** time since that was the standard.

Comment: What directory? I bet you are giving the wroing directory permission.

Comment: @Marco you're about 20 minutes off the pace...see Satya's last comment.